# AngularJS: How to avoid anonymous promise handlers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, anonymous-function, angular-promise

Recently with my client, we have chosen to follow [John Papa's AngularJS Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide)*.

I am currently going through the current codebase in order to make sure that there is no anonymous function left behind. However, I run into the case of a some promise handlers that require parameters set not by the response/rejection of the promise, but by another function or param. I have made some attempts at passing those parameters in the call back, but I failed.

```
function testPromise() {
  setPromiseAsPending();

  var timestamp = new Date().toString();

  firstModel.callPromise()
  // option 1: use of anonymous functions. works, but not the aim.
    // .then(
    //   function () {
    //     onPromiseResolved(timestamp);
    //   },
    //   function () {
    //     onPromiseRejected(timestamp);
    //   }
    // )['finally'](setPromiseAsCompleted);

  // option 2: naming functions in context. works, but less than ideal in our context.
    .then(
      function onPromiseResolved() {
        secondModel.logPromiseResults('this promise has been resolved on ' + timestamp);
      },
      function onPromiseRejected() {
        secondModel.logPromiseResults('this promise has been rejected on ' + timestamp);
      }
    )['finally'](setPromiseAsCompleted);

  // option 3: passing functions as variables. not good: doesn't work, missing the parameter.
    // .then(
    //   onPromiseResolved,
    //   onPromiseRejected
    // )['finally'](setPromiseAsCompleted);

  // option 4: calling functions with parameters. not good: both functions called.
    // .then(
    //   onPromiseResolved(timestamp),
    //   onPromiseRejected(timestamp)
    // )['finally'](setPromiseAsCompleted);

  // option 5: how do i pass the parameter to only be used when the function is called?
```

The goal here is to make sure that there is no function declared within a function, so that each function is named and declared at the same level. We aim to reduce the length of functions, especially to make them more testable.

See the code excerpt above and let me know if you have a suggestion. Keep in mind that this is not the code that we use, but rather a minimal prototype that mimes how the function works.

See [the code in github](https://github.com/jansensan/angularjs-promises-with-named-callbacks) as well, if that helps you. Thanks in advance for your help.

* Do not get into a religious debate about the styleguide, this is not the subject of this question.

Comment: I'm looking at the linked style guide and I don't see the point about declaring functions on the same level and naming them all. Naming your inline functions is a nice thing to do, but shouldn't be applied without thinking. Pure ["partials"](https://lodash.com/docs#partial) are a good example of what _not_ to name.

Comment: That style guide itself uses anonymous handlers for promises here: https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide/blob/master/README.md#return-a-promise-from-data-calls . I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here but the style guide seems to be OK with option 1.

Comment: @hon2a: naming all your functions is not only a nice thing to do, it's necessary when you have a huge codebase to debug and some 20 devs. I may concede that the inlining part may be necessary, but not avoiding the naming.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaumL I agree the style guide does not tackle all situations, but as a team this is what we aim for. As I mentioned to hon2a, I may indeed have to concede the part of declaring all the functions at the function/class level though.

Comment: It's not that it doesn't tackle all situations - it's that it _disagrees_ with you. The style guide uses an unnamed promise callback itself (in the examples) which you think it forbids. If it forbids them then why does it use them in the style guide examples themselves? 

Anyway, personally I agree with you (about naming callbacks in a large code base) and disagree with the styleguide (just like you) - what we do is just named function expressions - ala `.then(function gotUser(user){ /* do work here */ }).catch(function failedToGetUser(user){ /* do work here */ })...`

Comment: @user4291649 The reason to name your functions is to have comprehensible call-stacks when debugging. _Not_ naming the functions that just provide closures and don't execute their own code is just as essential.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Function.prototype.bind`:

```
.then(
   onPromiseResolved.bind(null, timestamp),
   onPromiseRejected.bind(null, timestamp)
)['finally'](setPromiseAsCompleted);
```

Then your function will be called just as if you did `onPromiseResolved(timestamp)` like in option 1.

See [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for more information.

Comment: I didn't know this, I will look into it and see if it answers our need or if it's something that the tech lead even accepts for us going forward. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are not to *pass* the parameter. You just need to *declare* it in your function definition.

Either use an "external" function declaration

```
function onPromiseResolved(timestamp) {
    secondModel.logPromiseResults('this promise has been resolved with ' + timestamp);
}
function onPromiseRejected(err) {
    secondModel.logPromiseResults('this promise has been rejected with ' + err);
}

….then(onPromiseResolved, onPromiseRejected)
```

or a named function expression:

```
.then(function onPromiseResolved(timestamp) {
    secondModel.logPromiseResults('this promise has been resolved with ' + timestamp);
}, function onPromiseRejected(err) {
    secondModel.logPromiseResults('this promise has been rejected with ' + err);
})
```

---

> The goal here is to make sure that there is no function declared within a function, so that each function is named and declared at the same level

That's rather futile. Sometimes, you just *need* closures (as you don't want all variables to be static globals). Of course, you can still move them out and pass the closure variables explicitly as arguments:

```
function makeOnPromiseResolvedHandler(closurevars) {
    return function onPromiseResolved(timestamp) {
        secondModel.logPromiseResults('this promise has been resolved with ' + timestamp);
        // use closurevars in here
    };
}

….then(makeOnPromiseResolvedHandler(…), …)
```

Comment: In 2nd part of your anwser you're getting into the "religious debate" that OP wanted to avoid :P Actually, when you follow the guide you [don't get globals because of IIFE](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide/blob/master/README.md#style-y010).

Comment: @Bergi: I agree that your first example if the promise response would contain the necessary information, however as I explained "I run into the case of a some promise handlers that require parameters set not by the response/rejection of the promise [...]" To be more exact, we call a webservice (UI agnostic), and the var is a redirect URL according to the situation. I may indeed have to go with the named function expression you mention since naming is more important.

Comment: @m01: thanks for making that argument, we indeed work with IIFEs.

Comment: @m01: Well, *global* might have been the wrong word - let's call them *static* variables. But if your object is not a singleton, you will want to avoid them. When you have closures and want to move the functionality inside them to the top level, you will need to pass all the closure arguments as parameters instead - and use partial application to make the callback functions. Which can be done using closures (like in my `makeHandler` snippet) or using `.bind` like in your answer.

Comment: @user4291649: You're right, my initial answer (the first part) doesn't focus on your actual question.